# Crear archivos con directorio en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo

Tengo que hacer una archivo pero quiero darle una dirección en especifico:

```
File archivo =  new File("subCarpeta\archivo.txt");
```

Estoy trabajando con NetBeans 8.2 y quiero crear un archivo de texto en la misma carpeta que en la que está el programa o en una subcarpeta a la que están todos los programas, pero sin la necesidad de colocar toda la ruta

```
c:\Usuario\Carpeta1\Carpeta2\Netbeans\programa\src\archivo.txt
```

Si bien al momento de crear un archivo, únicamente asignando el nombre, se crea el archivo en la carpeta general del proyecto, yo quiero moverlo a otra carpeta.

¿Hay alguna forma de crear un archivo y asignarle una ruta en especifico sin la necesidad de colocar el disco u otras carpetas padre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como se sugiere en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634906) en la comunidad de Stackoverflow, puedes usar la función `mkdirs()` para que los directorios intermedios sean creados.

Nos queda un código como el siguiente:

```
File archivo = new File("subCarpeta/archivo.txt");
// Obtenemos un objeto File para la carpeta contenedora
File carpeta = archivo.getParentFile();
// Creamos los directorios solo si no existen
if (!carpeta.exists()){
    carpeta.mkdirs();
}
```

Posteriormente puedes crear tu archivo sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias, si funciona :D