# JAVA El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: java

Estoy utilizando el patrón MVC para crear una aplicación que permita Crear, Leer, Actualizar y Eliminar datos de usuarios, pero al momento de crear me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo solucionarlo?, el código que cree para generar el archivo es el siguiente:

```
public class Archivo {
    private ObjectInputStream flujoEntrada;
    private ObjectOutputStream flujoSalida;

public Archivo(File miArchivo) {
    if (!miArchivo.exists()) {
        try {
            miArchivo.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}

public void escribirEnArchivo(List<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes, File miArchivo) {

    try {
        flujoSalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(miArchivo));
        flujoSalida.writeObject(listaEstudiantes);
        flujoSalida.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Estudiante> leerArchivo(File miArchivo) {
    
    ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();
    if (miArchivo.length() != 0) {
        try {
            flujoEntrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(miArchivo));
            listaEstudiantes = (ArrayList<Estudiante>) flujoEntrada.readObject();
            flujoEntrada.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listaEstudiantes;
}
```

y con este metodo creo al usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Heidy, dentro de tu proyecto agrega el directorio /datos y el archivo datos_estudiantes.dat. El error que se muestra es porque no existe este archivo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que debo crear el archivo .dat, en ese caso que estoy haciendo mal? porque no se creo el archivo?

Comment: Ok, si debes crearlo entonces usa mkdirs(), actualicé mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo intente pero al ejecutar el programa no crea el archivo .dat crea una nueva carpeta con ese nombre

Answer (score 2):

El error indica que no existe el archivo que tratas de abrir en la ruta `datos/datos_estudiantes.dat`, dentro de tu proyecto agrega el directorio `/datos` y dentro el archivo `datos_estudiantes.dat`

En este caso puedes validar si existe o no el archivo mediante el método `.exists()` :

```
fuenteDatos = new File("datos/datos_estudiantes.dat");
if(fuenteDatos.exists()){
  //Existe archivo, realiza proceso.
}else{
  //NO Existe archivo.
}
```

---

Si deseas crear el archivo usa el método .mkdirs();

```
    fuenteDatos = new File("datos/datos_estudiantes.dat");
    if(fuenteDatos.exists()){
      //Existe archivo, realiza proceso.
    }else{
      //NO Existe archivo, lo crea
      fuenteDatos.mkdirs();
    }
```

Comment: También puede crear los directorios faltantes automáticamente. Puede revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/468113/169744) que di a otra pregunta si quiere saber cómo.